# Too many optionals making code messy in Swift

Tags: json, swift, option-type

I am parsing some JSON, and this is the first time I'm doing so on Swift. Recently, I have been avoiding using forced downcasts as it's a bad practice.

Unfortunately, the downside to this is that my code has become a lot more messier, especially in this particular case of trying to parse JSON.

This is my code:

```
if let dic = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(currentData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
    student["roll"] = dic["roll"] as? Int
    student["firstName"] = dic["name"]?.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").first
    student["lastName"] = dic["name"]?.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").last

    var subjects = [[String: AnyObject?]]()

    if let dicSubs = dic["subs"] as? [AnyObject] {
        for dicSub in dicSubs {
            var sub = [String: AnyObject?]()

            sub["name"] = dicSub["name"] as? String

            if let code = dicSub["code"] as? String {
                sub["code"] = Int(code)
            }
            if let theory = dicSub["theory"] as? String {
                sub["theory"] = Int(theory)
            }
            if let prac = dicSub["prac"] as? String {
                sub["prac"] = Int(prac)
            }

            subjects.append(sub)
        }
    }

    student["subjects"] = subjects
}
```

The output produced is littered with Optionals this way, making it almost unusable. I have a feeling I am doing something wrong, since the Objective C version of this code is much cleaner and shorter.

Is there any way I could make this better?

If needed, here's the output produced:

```
[  
  roll:Optional(1234567),
  firstName:Optional("FIRSTNAME"),
  lastName:Optional("LASTNAME"),
  subjects:Optional(  [  
    [  
      "code":Optional(123),
      "theory":Optional(73),
      "name":Optional(REDACTED)
    ],
    [  
      "code":Optional(123),
      "theory":Optional(76),
      "name":Optional(REDACTED)
    ],
    [  
      "code":Optional(123),
      "theory":Optional(48),
      "name":Optional(REDACTED)
    ],
    [  
      "code":Optional(123),
      "theory":Optional(75),
      "prac":Optional(19),
      "name":Optional(REDACTED)
    ],
    [  
      "code":Optional(123),
      "theory":Optional(69),
      "prac":Optional(18),
      "name":Optional(REDACTED)
    ],
    [  
      "code":Optional(123),
      "theory":Optional(63),
      "prac":Optional(28),
      "name":Optional(REDACTED)
    ]
  ]  )
])
```

Comment: Could you add an extension to Swift dictionaries that turns a possible string into an optional Int?

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes, it did occur to me, but that seems to be a hack-y solution to me, so I was wondering if people would have better suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unwrap the Optionals (you're already doing it for some of them, do it for all):

```
if let roll = dic["roll"] as? Int {
    student["roll"] = roll
}
```

Also, the initializer `Int(...)` returns an Optional, so you have to unwrap it too with Optional binding:

```
if let code = dicSub["code"] as? String, let myInt = Int(code) {
    sub["code"] = myInt
}
```

Comment: Is that the best way to go? That'd add 3 lines of code for each key I'm parsing, and I was wondering if it could be shorter.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it by hand. If you find it cumbersome, you could use a library like SwiftyJSON which will unwrap everything for you automatically, *but* will add boilerplate and overhead in other places, so... your choice. :) Both ways are ok. Personnalyy I prefer by hand when the JSON is not too complex, that way I know exactly what is happening.

Comment: Thanks! I like your reasoning about knowing what is happening. Guess I'll go that way, though will give SwiftyJSON a try.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Indeed decoding JSON by hand in Swift can be verbose at times, but I find it's not actually a problem: with time, you will add your own extensions and methods to avoid typing the same stuff over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the speeds you need I would suggest you to use some third party library for JSON communication. A good example is:

[SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

You could check out a tutorial about it over here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial

Comment: SwiftyJSON will save you countless hours.  It makes parsing JSON as easy as comparing two numbers.